# Kendo React DatetimePicker with Persian calendar

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, datetimepicker, persian-calendar, jalali-calendar

I read [this article](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/dateinputs/globalization/) of kendo about globalization and [cldr document](https://github.com/unicode-cldr/cldr-json) and found that I should use [cldr-cal-persian-full](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cldr-cal-persian-full) for implementing Persian calendar in Kendo React DatetimePicker, but my code below it causes an error that "*Cannot read property 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss' of undefined*":

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { DateTimePicker } from "@progress/kendo-react-dateinputs";
import {
IntlProvider,
load,
loadMessages,
LocalizationProvider
} from "@progress/kendo-react-intl";

import likelySubtags from "cldr-core/supplemental/likelySubtags.json";
import currencyData from "cldr-core/supplemental/currencyData.json";
import weekData from "cldr-core/supplemental/weekData.json";

import numbers from "cldr-numbers-full/main/fa/numbers.json";

import caPersian from "cldr-cal-persian-full/main/fa/ca-persian.json";

import dateFields from "cldr-dates-full/main/fa/dateFields.json";
import timeZoneNames from "cldr-dates-full/main/fa/timeZoneNames.json";
import faMessages from "../data/fa.json";

load(
likelySubtags,
currencyData,
weekData,
numbers,
caPersian,
dateFields,
timeZoneNames
);

loadMessages(faMessages, "fa");

class KendoDatetime extends Component {
state = { locale: "fa" };
render() {
    return (
    <LocalizationProvider language={this.state.locale}>
        <IntlProvider locale={this.state.locale}>
        <div className="example-wrapper row">
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-12 example-config">
            <h5>
                Current local - <em>{this.state.locale}</em>
            </h5>
            </div>
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-6 example-col">
            <DateTimePicker />
            </div>
        </div>
        </IntlProvider>
    </LocalizationProvider>
    );
}
}

export default KendoDatetime;
```

Does the Kendo support Persian calendar?

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/intl/globalization-support/ does not list DatetimePicker, but does DatePicker and TimePicker . Can you make DatePicker work?

Comment: @GaloisGirl, I tested it and the result is the same...

Comment: I have same problem. Could you find any way to use Persian date picker?